# UWP Binding in Style Setter not working

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, setter, itemcontainerstyle

I have problem with creating xaml control. I'm writing new project in VS 2015 in universal app. I want create grid. In this grid I want to have a button. In model I specifi the column (Level) and Row.
this is my code:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TechnologyList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="14*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="14*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="14*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="14*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="14*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="14*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="14*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Control">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Level}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I get a error in line `<Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Level}" />` 
The error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED) was in edytor not in running code.
What is wrong? In "old" WPF everything was OK but in Universal App for Windows 10 I have a error.
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: How can I  do something like this n UWP ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As noted in the section *Migration notes* on the [Setter.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.setter.value) page on MSDN, UWP/Windows Runtime does not support bindings in Style Setters.

> Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) and Microsoft Silverlight
>   supported the ability to use a Binding expression to supply the Value
>   for a Setter in a Style. The Windows Runtime doesn't support a Binding
>   usage for Setter.Value (the Binding won't evaluate and the Setter has
>   no effect, you won't get errors, but you won't get the desired result
>   either). When you convert XAML styles from WPF or Silverlight XAML,
>   replace any Binding expression usages with strings or objects that set
>   values, or refactor the values as shared {StaticResource} markup
>   extension values rather than Binding-obtained values.

A workaround could be a helper class with attached properties for the source paths of the bindings. It creates the bindings in code behind in a PropertyChangedCallback of the helper property:

```
public class BindingHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty GridColumnBindingPathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "GridColumnBindingPath", typeof(string), typeof(BindingHelper),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, GridBindingPathPropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GridRowBindingPathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "GridRowBindingPath", typeof(string), typeof(BindingHelper),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, GridBindingPathPropertyChanged));

    public static string GetGridColumnBindingPath(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(GridColumnBindingPathProperty);
    }

    public static void SetGridColumnBindingPath(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(GridColumnBindingPathProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetGridRowBindingPath(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(GridRowBindingPathProperty);
    }

    public static void SetGridRowBindingPath(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(GridRowBindingPathProperty, value);
    }

    private static void GridBindingPathPropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var propertyPath = e.NewValue as string;

        if (propertyPath != null)
        {
            var gridProperty =
                e.Property == GridColumnBindingPathProperty
                ? Grid.ColumnProperty
                : Grid.RowProperty;

            BindingOperations.SetBinding(
                obj,
                gridProperty,
                new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath(propertyPath) });
        }
    }
}
```

You would use them in XAML like this:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="local:BindingHelper.GridColumnBindingPath" Value="Level"/>
        <Setter Property="local:BindingHelper.GridRowBindingPath" Value="Row"/>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

---

For a simple workaround for absolute positioning (i.e. binding the `Canvas.Left` and `canvas.Top` properties), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40069980/1136211).

Comment: Hm doesn't work for me. Is the Targettype in the ItemContainerStyle always ContentPresenter? If I set it to my ViewModel, I get a catrastrophic failure exception.

Comment: @MatthiasMüller, I think that's correct. I had a similar problem. The ContentPresenter is the parent of the whole template, so I believe it is the correct target type.

Comment: The item container type of an ItemsControl is ContentPresenter, hence the TargetType of an ItemContainerStyle must be ContentPresenter.

Comment: Direct link to [Migration Notes in docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Setter#migration-notes) and open [WinUI issue on this topic](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/719#issuecomment-494252661).

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add my experience of this `BindingHelper` idea from @clemens. It's a neat solution but I found that when targetting a `ListViewItem` the binding wouldn't access the underlying view model. After debugging it, I found that I needed to make sure the binding was relative to the `ListViewItem` itself and the associated `.Content` property to enable it to correctly link to the item's view model.

My particular use case was to set the `IsTabStop` property of the `ListViewItem` based on a view model value:

```
private static void BindingPathPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue is string propertyPath)
    {
        var binding = new Binding
        {  
            Path = new PropertyPath($"Content.{propertyPath}"),
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
            RelativeSource = new RelativeSource
            {
                Mode = RelativeSourceMode.Self
            }
        };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(obj, Control.IsTabStopProperty, binding);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps if anyone else has the problem.