# itemscontrol in UWP doesnt bind to coordinates of observablecollection items

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

My Code does not bind to the X and Y property of the items in the observable Collection. What is wrong:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LED}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Background="SkyBlue"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Ellipse Stroke="{Binding Color}" Fill="{Binding FillColor}" StrokeThickness="1" Width="40" Height="40"></Ellipse>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

It does bind to Color and FillColor.
Here is the Shape class, that is stored in the ObservableCollection LED:

```
class Shape
{
    public int X { get; private set; }
    public int Y { get; private set; }
    public string Color { get; private set; }
    public string FillColor { get; private set; }

    public Shape (int x, int y, string color, string fillColor)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Color = color;
        FillColor = fillColor;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for the [Setter.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.setter.value) property has the following note:

> Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) and Microsoft Silverlight supported the ability to use a Binding expression to supply the Value for a Setter in a Style. **The Windows Runtime doesn't support a Binding usage for Setter.Value (the Binding won't evaluate and the Setter has no effect, you won't get errors, but you won't get the desired result either).** When you convert XAML styles from WPF or Silverlight XAML, replace any Binding expression usages with strings or objects that set values, or refactor the values as shared {StaticResource} markup extension values rather than Binding-obtained values.

As a workaround, you could try using a RenderTransform instead:

```
<Ellipse Stroke="{Binding Color}" Fill="{Binding FillColor}" StrokeThickness="1" Width="40" Height="40">
    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding X}" Y="{Binding Y}"/>
    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
</Ellipse>
```

Comment: Somehow it does not plot exactly the same as Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top. Any ideas?