# Display Graph with Vertices and Edges in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

My goal is to display a simple `Graph` in a UWP application. The graph contains a list of vertices and edges. A `Vertex` has an absolute Position and should be displayed in the View correspondingly. An `Edge` contains two vertices and should be represented as a simple line between one vertex to the other. Additionally it would also be nice if those GraphItems (Vertex and Edge) were selectable in the view.

So far I've tried to use a ListBox with it's ItemsPanel set to a Canvas so that the items were selectable. I've created my own `GraphDataTemplateSelector` that is inherited from `DataTemplateSelector` for choosing whether a vertex or an edge should be drawn. My ViewModel returns the graph as an ObservableCollection of objects which is used as the ItemsSource of the ListBox. I've tried to position the elements with the `ItemContainerStyle` and binding the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties. But according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40069980/1136211) the binding for `Setter.Value` isn't supported under UWP so I used the workaround with the `RenderTransform` described in the same post.

The problem with this approach is that the selection rectangle of the elements always stays at the top left corner of the canvas. As far as I understand if I'm selecting a Canvas as the ItemsPanel of the view it's children will be presented in a ContentPresenter. My guess is that this is caused due to the fact the RenderTransform is only applied to the DataTemplate and not to the ContentPresenter itself.

My question now is how can I solve this problem, so that the selection rectangle moves along with the elements? Maybe this isn't the best way for achieving this goal and there's a better solution for this? Thanks for your time and help!

My XAML-Code:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:VertexModel" x:Key="VertexTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform X="{x:Bind Position.X}" Y="{x:Bind Position.Y}"/>
                </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <Ellipse Fill="Red" Height="40" Width="40" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Black"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:EdgeModel" x:Key="EdgeTemplate">
        <Line X1="{x:Bind StartVertex.Position.X}" 
              Y1="{x:Bind StartVertex.Position.Y}" 
              X2="{x:Bind EndVertex.Position.X}" 
              Y2="{x:Bind EndVertex.Position.Y}" 
              Stroke="DarkGreen" StrokeThickness="2"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <templateSelector:GraphDataTemplateSelector x:Key="GraphDataTemplateSelector"
                                                VertexTemplate="{StaticResource VertexTemplate}"
                                                EdgeTemplate="{StaticResource EdgeTemplate}"/>
</Page.Resources>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Graph}"
         ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource GraphDataTemplateSelector}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

My GraphDataTemplateSelector:

```
public class GraphDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate VertexTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate EdgeTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)
    {
        if (item is VertexModel)
            return VertexTemplate;
        if (item is EdgeModel)
            return EdgeTemplate;

        return base.SelectTemplateCore(item);
    }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        return SelectTemplateCore(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question now is how can I solve this problem, so that the selection rectangle moves along with the elements

The selection rectangle is actually the `BorderBackground` rectangle which is inside the [ListViewItem control template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx) at default. 
The transform you defined inside the `DateTemplate` is only applied to the `ContentPresenter` of the control template, not also to the `BorderBackground` rectangle. So you may need to define a new `ListViewItem` style for the `ListView` and set the transform for the `BorderBackground` rectangle with the `position` data.

As you known you may not able to bind data to the `setter.value`, but you should be able to bind the data to the elements inside the control template with `Binding`. Code sample as follows, define a new style in the page resource:

```
<Page.Resources>
...
 <Style x:Key="ListViewItemExpanded" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Grid
                        x:Name="ContentBorder"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">                     
                        <Rectangle
                            x:Name="BorderBackground"
                            Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}"
                            Opacity="0"
                            Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform X="{Binding Position.X}" Y="{Binding Position.Y}" />
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Grid
                            x:Name="ContentPresenterGrid"
                            Margin="0,0,0,0"
                            Background="Transparent">
                            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" />
                            </Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <ContentPresenter
                                x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" />

                        </Grid> 
                        <TextBlock
                            x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            Foreground="{x:Null}"
                            Opacity="0"
                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            Text="Xg" />
                        <Rectangle
                            x:Name="PlaceholderRect"
                            Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                            Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        <Rectangle
                            x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                            Opacity="0"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                        <Border
                            x:Name="MultiSelectSquare"
                            Width="20"
                            Height="20"
                            Margin="12,0,0,0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="2"
                            Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <Border.Clip>
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,20,20">
                                    <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="MultiSelectClipTransform" />
                                    </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                                </RectangleGeometry>
                            </Border.Clip>
                            <Border.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="MultiSelectCheckBoxTransform" />
                            </Border.RenderTransform>
                            <FontIcon
                                x:Name="MultiSelectCheck"
                                Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                                Opacity="0"
                                FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                FontSize="16"
                                Glyph="&#xE73E;"
                                Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock
                            x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayText"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Margin="18,9,0,0"
                            Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
                            Opacity="0"
                            FontFamily="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"
                            FontSize="26.667"
                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DragItemsCount}"
                            TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Duration="0"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1" />
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Duration="0"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1" />
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Duration="0:0:0"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheck"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Duration="0"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1" />
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Duration="0:0:0"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheck"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Duration="0"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1" />
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Duration="0:0:0"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheck"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Duration="0"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1" />
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Enabled" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Duration="0"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>                                
                            ...
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DataVirtualizationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="DataAvailable" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="DataPlaceholder">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderHintStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="NoReorderHint" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="BottomReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation
                                            Direction="Bottom"
                                            ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                                            TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="TopReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation
                                            Direction="Top"
                                            ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                                            TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="RightReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation
                                            Direction="Right"
                                            ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                                            TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="LeftReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation
                                            Direction="Left"
                                            ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                                            TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="NoReorderHint" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DragStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="NotDragging" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Dragging">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Duration="0"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" />
                                        <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="DraggingTarget">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DropTargetItemThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingPrimary">
                                    <Storyboard>                                           
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Duration="0"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Duration="0"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Duration="0"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" />
                                        <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground" />
                                        <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText" />
                                        <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingSecondary">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="DraggedPlaceholder">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="NotDragging" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>   
</Page.Resources>
```

And set the style to the `ListViewItem`.

```
<ListView
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemExpanded}"
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource GraphDataTemplateSelector}"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Graph1}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
...
</ListView>
```

And the result:

[image]

You should be able just set transform to the `ContentBorder` element, in that case you will not set transform inside `Datetemplate` again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solutions works quite well just for the fact that I applied the `RenderTransform` to the base grid and not to the `BorderBackground Rectangle`. With this change it does exactly what it needs to do. Thank you very much.