# UWP/XAML: Drawing and moving listbox items on canvas

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, uwp, listbox

I want to draw `listbox` items on a `Canvas`, place them somewhere, and then move them around, finding inspiration in the following very good example [Brewer Floating Content](https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2016/02/08/a-floating-panel-control-for-uwp/). However I don't want to duplicate this specific example from the blog.

Hence I attempt to draw items on `listbox` with a `Canvas`, but fail again, though in WPF this works easily.

The XAML code is:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ThingTemplate" x:DataType="local:Thing">
        <Border Width="150" BorderBrush="#FF9B3333" BorderThickness="2"
                ManipulationMode="TranslateX, TranslateY, TranslateInertia"
                ManipulationDelta="Border_ManipulationDelta">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border Background="#FF9B3333" Grid.Row="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Comment}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Foreground="Black" Padding="4" />
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>    
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="ThingCanvas" Grid.Row="1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ThingTemplate}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

and the source code-behind:

```
public sealed partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            var newThing = new Thing() { Comment = "Item" + i.ToString() };
            ThingCanvas.Items.Add(newThing);
        }
    }

    private void Border_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var left = Canvas.GetLeft(this) + e.Delta.Translation.X;
        var top = Canvas.GetTop(this) + e.Delta.Translation.Y;
        Canvas.SetLeft(this, left);
        Canvas.SetTop(this, top);
    }
}

public class Thing
    {
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
```

Strange is that the `Canvas` cannot access to `IsItemsHost` property, which is set in WPF.

Also hindering is that style setters cannot be databound in UWP, so that `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` cannot be bound.

Thank you for helping me advance on this topic.

RudiAcitivity

Comment: You don't need to set `IsItemsHost`. For the missing binding capability in Style Setters, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33582406/1136211).