# Apply dynamic value to Setter property in UWP RadDataGrid

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, telerik, telerik-grid

I have this XAML in my RadDataGrid that changes the background color of a selected row to red based on the value returned by the ValidateModuleBank property defined in my model.

```
<tg:RadDataGrid.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="gridPrimitives:SelectionRegionBackgroundControl">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ValidateModuleBank,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
  </Style>
</tg:RadDataGrid.Resources>
```

I looked online and it says that UWP does not support binding to a property in a style. So, how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You could try this workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33582406/6782612

Comment: @Bite, I already tried your link before posting my question. I am having trouble understanding it and how it relates to my question.

Comment: Where did not you understand?