# How to bind the color of a row in controls:DataGrid by binding with the value of a column in that row in UWP C#?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

For a specific values in a row of a column, how to change the row background color in UWP C#>

I have used controls:DataGrid to show the values of a DataTable in UWP. I am trying to bind the color of a row based on a value in "Color" column of DataTable. If "Color" column is "Red" of a row, I have to set Row Background "Red", or green otherwise.

```xml
<controls:DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="controls:DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ColumnForColorInDataTable}" />
    </Style>
</controls:DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

The code portion is from my xaml file.

Comment: you are using which datagrid ?

Comment: yes. I am using datagrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XAML in UWP is different from WPF, and writing the bind content in the `Setter` does not take effect. Currently DataGrid belongs to community control, and there is still a gap between WPF's DataGrid. To achieve your goals, I recommend using **ListView** for a higher degree of personalization.

But with regard to your goal of changing the row background color. There is currently no direct way for the `DataGrid` to do this. But there is still a Hack method to achieve your purpose.

Each row of the DataGrid is composed of multiple cells. It is difficult to control a row accurately, but we can control the performance of each cell.

Suppose we have a **Person** class with a `Name` and `ColumnForColorInDataTable` properties.

```xml
<Page
    ...
    >
    <Grid>
        <controls:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{x:Bind PersonCollection}">
            <controls:DataGrid.Columns>

                <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn
                    Header="Name"
                    Width="SizeToHeader">

                    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="Person">
                            <Border Background="{Binding ColumnForColorInDataTable}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <!-- Other Columns-->

            </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        </controls:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

In this way, let a row of cells maintain the same color, disguised to achieve your purpose.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I use the following code snippet below, I makes red for all cell. I am trying to make for a specific value of color in a data table.

```xml
<controls:DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="controls:DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</controls:DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: Hi, your code snippet will make the background color of all lines turn red, it will not change according to your data, you also found this. The answer I mean, with the `DataTemplate`, set the cells of a row that need to be changed to the same color, not all the cells of the entire DataGrid.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of [this post on binding in UWP Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573929/uwp-binding-in-style-setter-not-working) - which is not supported by UWP at this time. See [Migration Notes in docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Setter#migration-notes) and open [WinUI issue on this topic](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/719#issuecomment-494252661).

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT  is it possible to show a `ListView` example, as you suggest is better? where a hack is not needed?

Comment: @RichardZhang do I understand correctly that `ColumnForColorInDataTable` is a text column that holds color names, like Red or Blue? Thus the bind reads the text to set its background. As if you had `Border Background="Red"` ?

Comment: @RichardZhang, yes it works!  what a simple hack.